# Having some troubles finding a string for in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, xml

I'm doing some research in a MySQL database where some data is stored as XML. I already managed to find the string I was searching for:

```
select * from foo where Concat(foo) like '%bar%';
```

Now I'm trying to find only entries where "bar" appears 2 times. In the table where I'm searching "bar" always appears once so I want to find the entries with at least 2x "bar".

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `REGEXP` method

```
select * from foo where Concat(foo) regexp '(bar).*(bar)';
```

Breakdown

`()`- First capturing group

`bar` - The expression to be captured

`.` - Matches any character

`*` - Matches zero or more of a character

`(bar)` - Second capturing group

https://regex101.com/r/wM3wX9/1

From the MySQL documentation

> Performs a pattern match of a string expression expr against a pattern pat. The pattern can be an extended regular expression, the syntax for which is discussed later in this section. Returns 1 if expr matches pat; otherwise it returns 0. If either expr or pat is NULL, the result is NULL. RLIKE is a synonym for REGEXP, provided for mSQL compatibility.

I also created an SQL Fiddle for this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49fd7/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `scalable` solution, which can easily used on any repeated times, such as 1, 2, 10, 100 and etc.

```
-- match twice
select * from foo where (length(foo) - replace(foo,'bar',''))/length('bar') = 2;

-- match 3 repeated times
select * from foo where (length(foo) - replace(foo,'bar',''))/length('bar') = 3;

-- match 100 repeated times
select * from foo where (length(foo) - replace(foo,'bar',''))/length('bar') = 100;
```

### Reference:

[SQL function to get count of how many times string appears in column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031526/sql-function-to-get-count-of-how-many-times-string-appears-in-column)